# Passing environment variable to custom GitHub actions running powershell

Tags: powershell, github-actions

Trying to implement a workflow running custom actions as a template.
As part of the process I have to pass a variable from the workflow to action and to use it in `Powershell` there.

As you can see, with `bash` it works like a charm...

Main workflow:

```
name: cicd service

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "main", "refs/tags/s*", "refs/tags/v*" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master", "main" ]

env:
  pod_name: 'cicd'
  compile_name: 'cicd'
  reg_name: 'cicd'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: enterprise-linux-runner
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
      - name: aaa
        shell: bash
        run: echo "Hello ${pod_name}"               <-- Output is Hello cicd as expected
      - name: Get tag
        uses: ./.github/templates/gettag
        with:
          dname: ${pod_name}
```

Reusable action:

```
name: gettag

inputs:
  dname:
    required: true

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: bbb
      shell: pwsh
      run: write-host "name ${{ inputs.dname }}"   <-- Output is "name "  :(
    - name: bbb
      shell: bash
      run: echo "name ${{ inputs.dname }}"         <-- Output is "name cicd" as expected
```

But as you can see in `Powershell` the input value seems to be empty. Any ideas what do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

With:

```yaml
dname: ${pod_name}
```

for both `bash` and `pwsh`, `${{ inputs.dbname }}` expands to:

```bash
${pod_name}
```

which is valid for `bash` to reference an env var.

But, for `pwsh`, it should be:

```bash
${env:pod_name}
```

See [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2) for more details.

Comment: But I need to pass the value and not a reference to environment variable ..

Comment: @EduardDubilyer: That's what I suspected. Then, you need to set it like this `dname: '${{ env.pod_name }}'`.